# Unable to bind a ResourceDictionary item to Rectangle.Child

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

When I try to bind a `ResourceDictionary` item against `Rectangle.Child`, I get an exception:

`ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.`

Here is an example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:PersonConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Child="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And the code behind:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Persons = new List<Person> {new Person("Female"), new Person("Male")};
    }

    public List<Person> Persons { get; private set; }
}

public class PersonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private ResourceDictionary Items { get; set; }

    public PersonConverterRes()
    {
        Items = new ResourceDictionary
            {
                {"Male", new Canvas() {
                                 Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                                 Height = 100, Width = 100}},
                {"Female", new Canvas() {
                                 Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta),
                                 Height = 100, Width = 100}}
            };
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Items[value.ToString()];
    }

    ...
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(String gender)
    {
        Gender = gender;
    }

    public String Gender { get; private set; }
}
```

But if I replace the `ResourceDictionary` with a plain `Dictionary<String, UIElement>` the binding works fine:

```
public class PersonConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private Dictionary<String, UIElement> Items { get; set; }

    public PersonConverterRes()
    {
        Items = new Dictionary<String, UIElement>
            {
                {"Male", new Canvas() {
                                 Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                                 Height = 100, Width = 100}},
                {"Female", new Canvas() {
                                 Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Magenta),
                                 Height = 100, Width = 100}}
            };
    }

    ...
}
```

Does anybody know what is causing this exception?

Note:
I have tried this under WinRT as well. There, the code doesn't throw an exception, but the binding still doesn't work if I use a `ResourceDictionary`. I guess it's probably failing silently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use databinding to bind to the `Child` property of a `Border` since it is not a `DependencyProperty`. This is why your ResourceDictionary approach does not work.

Also, databinding in WPF/Silvelight/WinRT fails silently by design (it's a feature, and a very useful one if used correctly), so your guess would be right on that.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this.

More elegant to set a the Canvas.Background with trigger

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Border <!-- set properties --> >
               <Canvas Height="100" Width="100">
                  <Canvas.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="Canvas">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding={Binding Gender} Value="Male">
                                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding={Binding Gender} Value="Female">
                                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Magenta"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                      </Style>
                  </Canvas.Style>
               </Canvas>
           </Border>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Of course, if I was just setting the Canvas.Background property, that's how I would do it. In my actual scenario however, I need to display different Canvas objects (each containing different children objects) depending on the value of some property of my databound object collection. That's why I'm trying to bind UIElement objects to Rectangle.Child. Still, this is a good answer to my simplified question :)

Comment: Ok, this is still a wrong approach. In your case then create different DataTemplates and use ItemTemplateSelector to decide which to show

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a better approach. I'll give that a go.